# how to debug specflow test in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, specflow, vscode-debugger

I have set up an 'nunit' .NET Core project in Visual Studio Code and successfully got my specflow tests running (when I run 'dotnet test' at the terminal).

Now I'd like to be able to debug a test -- but it doesn't stop at my breakpoint in my step file (I have set a breakpoint in my test code, then I click the 'Debug' icon on the left side and then click the Start Debugging button -- but the debugger doesn't stop at my breakpoint).

Does anyone know how to get this working?   (Thanks in advance for any thoughts.)

Comment: If you click on the left side you should see a red dot appearing. That is a debug break point.

Comment: I have done that, but when running the tests via 'dotnet test' the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: Are you trying to debug the source `Gherkin` code (Scenario / Feature / Given / When / Then) or are you setting a breakpoint in the generated C# code underneath? VS proper is able to step through the Gherkin code after you install the [SpecFlow plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowForVisualStudio), can't say I've tried with VS Code.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to debug the specflow test in visual studio code. Go into the cs generated feature e.g. the .feature.cs file.

You have the usual option "Debug All Test" next to the class name.
[Like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtPJ2.png)